# jQuery Won't Work

Tags: jquery, html

For some reason when I try and run a simple jQuery code it won't work. I beleive the code is correct and it's like my file isn't linked correctly. It also won't work on other pages with different code so I'm thinking it must be something with the way that jQuery is linked. My code is:

```
<!DOCTYPEhtml PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.min"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#toggle_message').click(function() {
    var value = $('#toggle_message').attr('value');
    $('#message').toggle('fast');

    if (value == 'Hide') {
        $('#toggle_message').attr('value', 'Show');
    } else if (value == 'Show') {
        $('#toggle_message').attr('value', 'Hide');
        }
    }
});
$('#toggle_message').click();
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="Hide" id="toggle_message" />
<p id="message">This is a paragraph that will disappear</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help is appreciated. Also, my jQuery file is only 4 lines long.. Is that normal?

Comment: Check your console for any type of `$ is undefined` message.

Comment: you first have to call the jquery ready function to load all the elements on the DOM

Comment: Yes, 4 lines long file is normal for minimized jQuery. Take a look of lengths of these lines.

Answer (score 5):

I suspect you forgot the `.js` in jQuery's file name. It should be:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
```

Also, yes, it is normal for the file to have very few lines. It is compressed, and each line is very long.

Additionally, [as Nudier mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10424748#comment13453018_10424748), binding to elements won't work until the page has loaded. You probably want to delay the binding until the page has loaded:

```
$(function() {
    $('#toggle_message').click(function() {
        // ...
    });
    $('#toggle_message').click();
});
```

Comment: Ok thanks, but it still won't work. The button does nothing when I click it. The code I have now is: $(function() { $('#toggle_message').click(function() { var value = $('#toggle_message').attr('value'); $('#message').toggle('fast'); if (value == 'Hide') { $('#toggle_message').attr('value', 'Show'); } else if (value == 'Show') { $('#toggle_message').attr('value', 'Hide'); } } $('#toggle_message').click(); }); }); And that won't post right in a comment but hopefully you can help. Sorry, I'm pretty new to jQuery as you can tell. Thanks for any help!

Comment: @user1371489: It looks like you've got one too many `});` at the end and the `}` closing the `.click(function() {` part should be a `});`

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your JQUERY code in the .ready function. Also, as mentioned above, the linked js may be incorrect. Feel free to try the following and change the Jquery source to your local copy if you want. Usually I just use the src from: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js

```
 <!DOCTYPEhtml PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

    <html>
    <head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#toggle_message').click(function() {
            var value = $('#toggle_message').attr('value');
            $('#message').toggle('fast');

            if (value == 'Hide') {
                $('#toggle_message').attr('value', 'Show');
            } else if (value == 'Show') {
                $('#toggle_message').attr('value', 'Hide');
                }
        });

        $('#toggle_message').click();
    });


    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <input type="button" value="Hide" id="toggle_message" />
    <p id="message">This is a paragraph that will disappear</p>
    </body>
    </html>
     $('#toggle_message').click();
    });
```